# Java - Returning a True Value in Accessor Method

Tags: java, boolean, accessor

I have two class files - one is a tester file which cannot be edited. I need to get my Accessor method to return a true value so that the tester file provides the correct output. I can only provide the coding that I believe is necessary because this is part of a homework assignment.

```
 public class CreditCard
 { //instance variables within CreditCard
      int[ ] array;
      int code = 0;
      String creditCard;
      boolean card;

 public boolean isValid( )
 { //Accessor boolean method
      check( );
      return card;

 CreditCard card = new CreditCard(creditCardNumber);
 card.check( ); //coding within tester file which cannot be changed
 if (card.isValid( )) {
      System.out.println("Valid");
 }
```

I have everything else done but I cannot get the tester file to produce Valid output. Based on the information provided, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Code you posted doesn't really make much sense to me. Why do you have `boolean card` as well as `CreditCard card`

Comment: I believe that's his instantiation inside of his Main method, he just didn't separate them very well. The better question is why is he calling `check()` and then calling it again inside of `isValid()`. I don't know how much we can help without the source to `check()`.

Comment: Thank you both. @MeetTitan, your comment was exactly what I needed. I removed check( ) within isValid( ) and changed return card; to return true;. Tested and works like a charm. Thanks again.

Comment: @new2coding, it would probably make more sense to keep `check()` inside `isValid()`, but to remove it elsewhere.